# Javascript, got stuck

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here][1]

I wanted to add  within js in for loop but it gave me an error the moment I put <, please tell me what to do?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp5ZG.jpg

````
    <body>
        <form >
        Enter number of employees <input type="number" id="n">
        <input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="Submit">
            <center>
               <input type="number" name="n">
               <script>
                
                     
                function fun()   { 
                let i=0;
                let v=document.getElementById("n").value;                             
                for(let i=0;i<v;i++)
                {
                    <input type="number" name="v"+i> /*error while using 
                                                       <, do not know 
                                                     why*/
                }
                }
            </script>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Please share your code not the image

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok, sure will do

Comment: The value of the input is a `string`. You need to convert it to a number like so: `for(let i=0;i<parseInt(v);i++)`

Comment: `<input type="number" name="v"+i> ` is not valid javascript (it's HTML) but you are using it within your script. Are you trying to add `input` elements to the DOM?

Comment: @pilchard yes, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form >
        Enter number of employees <input type="number" id="n">
        <input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="Submit">
            <center>
               <input type="number" name="n">
               <script>
                
                     
                function fun()   { 
                let i=0;
                let v=document.getElementById("n").value;                             
                for(let i=0;i<v;i++)
                {
                    var s = '<input type="number" name="v'+`${i}`+'">';
                    document.write(s);
                }
             
                }
            </script>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS:) NOT Recommended, but you can do this though